# How to transform a cube mesh into a diamond shape

Tags: javascript, three.js, mesh

Is there a way in three.js to turn a cube mesh shape into a diamond shape doing something like rotating the axis of the scale and then scaling it? I'm trying to create a flat-ish diamond shape, something like x50,y50,x10. If not, then what's the best way to create a diamond mesh, or a triangle mesh shape?

If you just turn the cube on its end and scale x you'll still have a (now imbalanced) rectangle shape, but if you turn it on it's end, reorient the axis of scale somehow so it's stretching across the middle from point to point, now you could just squeeze the cube with scale x, and you'd have a nice diamond shape with a thin waist.

For clarification, here's a pic of the mesh shape I am trying to make, ideally the diamond shape on the left, but the triangle shape will do also.

[image: Here's a pic of the shape I am trying to make]

So, is there some way to rotate the axis of the scale? Is that what `new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation` is for? How do I use that in this context?

[See plunker of my attempt here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Lz8X3LZ8mSlcXTG1Mf5p?p=preview). Clearly my `cube.scale.x = 0.5;` code is *not* working and needs the axis of transform to be shifted.

Here's the js:

```
cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                cube.rotation.z = Math.PI / 4 ;
                cube.position.y = 35;
                cube.scale.x = 0.5;
                scene.add( cube );
```

Comment: is this the shape that you want? http://jsfiddle.net/wkzvvzwk/

Comment: Thanks for clarification. No (but that's nice), I'll post an image in the original question about the shape I am trying to make. Thanks.

Comment: is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/3gxqboer/. If yes, I will turn it into an answer.

Comment: Yes exactly, brilliant find. Thanks so much. Wow that's so simple, it's just turning it on the z axis before scaling x? But isn't that what I was doing already? I'm missing something here.

Comment: How did you did that fiddle so quickly? Is there a resource list of mrdoobs jsfiddles?  I don't seem to be able to find a link on that fiddle.

Comment: @gaitat I'm googling for a triangle example too and not having much luck. Do you know of a link where I could find one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to create a hierarchy of objects, the inner object will rotate around the z-axis and the outer object will scale on the x-axis.

```
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
mesh.rotation.z = Math.PI / 4; // rotate by 45 degrees

var group = new THREE.Group();
group.add( mesh );
group.scale.x = 0.5; // scale by 0.5

scene.add( group );
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3gxqboer/

Comment: So in my case, with the code in the initial question, I need to wrap my cube in a group, then scale it. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert your cube or box into a diamond shape, then the easiest method is to transform your geometry using a pattern like this one:

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 100, 100, 20 );

geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationZ( Math.PI / 4 ) );
geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale( 1, 2, 1 ) ); // optional
```

Once you create your mesh, you still have the option of further scaling the mesh, itself.

```
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
mesh.scale.set( sz, sy, sz );
scene.add( mesh );
```

three.js r.71